# PostgreSQL 9.2: apply operation to every array member

Tags: postgresql

Let's say I'm trying to apply a division by 2 on an array

`SELECT unnest(array[1.0, 2.0, 3.0])::REAL/2`

This gives me three rows with the values 0.5, 1.0 and 1.5.

How do I then proceed to convert this back into an array? I tried

`SELECT array_agg(unnest(array[1.0, 2.0, 3.0])::REAL/2)`

But I get: `ERROR:  set-valued function called in context that cannot accept a set`

Extra question: How would I go about the same problem, but on multi-dimensional arrays?

`SELECT unnest(array[[1.0, 0.1], [2.0, 0.2]])::REAL/2`

I would want an answer like `"{{0.5,0.05},{1.0,0.1}}"`

Comment: Closely related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/8584119/398670, though that doesn't seem to consider multi-dim arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part is easy enough - you just need to add an extra level to aggregate everything.

```
select array_agg(val/2)
from (select unnest(array[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]) val) t
;
```

As for the multi-dimensional case, maybe something awkward like this?

```
create aggregate array_array_agg(anyarray) (
  sfunc=array_cat,
  stype=anyarray
)
;

select array_array_agg(val)
from
(
  select (select array[array_agg(val/2)]
          from (select unnest((array[[1.0, 0.1], [2.0, 0.2]])[i:i]) val) t) val
  from generate_series(1, array_length(array[[1.0, 0.1], [2.0, 0.2]], 1)) as i
) t
;
```

That uses array indexing and generate_series to step over each array, then applies the logic in the first step. I'm not sure how much cleaner it could be.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your first question, you can convert a result set to an `ARRAY` by simply doing:

```
SELECT ARRAY (SELECT unnest(array[1.0, 2.0, 3.0])::REAL/20)
```