# How to get corresponding names for each element of an Postgresql array

Tags: database, postgresql

I have two tables tablea and tableb. Their sturcture is:

```
tablea
  id   serial
  name varchar
  alg  integer[]

tableb
  id          serial
  description varchar
```

in tablea.alg field I have multiple numbers of substances like {1,17,55,97} and in the query I want to get names instead of numbers like:

```
name      | substances
organism1 | substance 1, substance 17, substance 55, substance 97
```

Can any1 suggest the right query?

Answer to simmilar question is on [StackOwerflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584119/how-to-apply-a-function-to-each-element-of-an-array-column-in-postgres), but how to use tables instead of fixed array values?

Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `unnest()` to get `algs` in separate rows, 
join `tableb` on the values and aggregate `description` with `string_agg()`:

```
select name, string_agg(description, ', ') substances
from (
    select name, unnest(alg) alg
    from tablea
    ) a
join tableb on alg = id
group by name;
```