# PostgreSQL: SELECT a function on all items in an array

Tags: arrays, postgresql, postgis, postgresql-9.3, sql-function

Consider a table with the following rows:

```
id       | bigint
polygons | geometry(Polygon,4326)[]
```

`SELECT`-ing the `polygons` row returns an array of unreadable binary data:

```
SELECT polygons FROM some_table WHERE id=405;
{0103000020E61000000100000006000000B84F039E5AC0E375243935C13F402...}
```

Using `st_AsText` on the first element returns a readable output:

```
SELECT st_AsText(polygons[1]) FROM some_table WHERE id=405;
POLYGON((-106.4689521119 31.7547183717742 ...)
```

Unsurprisingly, the function only works on an element, not on an array:

```
SELECT st_AsText(polygons) FROM some_table WHERE id=405;
ERROR:  function st_astext(geometry[]) does not exist
```

Putting it in Python lingo, I'm looking for the equivalent of `print [st_AsText(p) for i in polygons]` in PostgreSQL.

**How do I run a PostgreSQL function on all elements of an array within a SELECT statement, a-la Python's list comprehension?**

**Addendum**
I think that this isn't a strict duplicate, because [`How to apply a function to each element of an array column in Postgres?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584119/how-to-apply-a-function-to-each-element-of-an-array-column-in-postgres) handles an inline array (e.g. `FROM unnest(ARRAY[1.53224,0.23411234])`), while this question handles a `SELECT` statement from a table which contains an array column. The conversion isn't trivial, at least for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`unnest()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html):

```
SELECT st_AsText(p) 
FROM some_table, unnest(polygons) p 
WHERE id=405;
```